# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in > components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: > object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting a warning and an error when I load my project. I am at video 68 at the moment.

Warning:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `WeatherList`.

And an error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   object. Check the render method of `WeatherList`.

When I check my render method for the WeatherList component I don't see anything that would cause this error:

```
render() {
    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Temperature (C)</th>
                    <th>Pressure (hPa)</th>
                    <th>Humidity (%)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
 }
```

They both point to this render method as the source of the error.

**Edit:**

The WeatherList component is being imported and rendered in the App component.

```
import WeatherList from "../containers/weather_list";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <WeatherList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The renderWeather funtion returns table data from mapping over an array:

```
renderWeather(cityData) { 
    const name = cityData.city.name;
    const temps = _.map(
      cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp),
      temp => temp - 273
    ); 
    const pressures = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.pressure);
    const humidities = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
    const { lon, lat } = cityData.city.coord; 
    return (
      <tr key={name}>
        <td>
          <GoogleMap lon={lon} lat={lat} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Chart data={temps} color={"red"} units="C" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Chart data={pressures} color={"green"} units="hPa" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Chart data={humidities} color={"blue"} units="%" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
```

Comment: How are you importing WeatherList component ?

Comment: It probably means that the `renderWeather` method does not return anything.

Comment: We would need more than this code to figure out

Comment: I've added more of my code to the original post.

Comment: I fixed it. Turns out I wasn't correctly exporting my Google Map component.